# Change metric of a disconnected interface with netsh

Tags: vpn, powershell, routing, netsh

I am creating a Wapt_package to deploy VPN Interface on our user's terminal.

I create the VPN interface without issue, but we need to set the metric of the vpn interface to 1.
add-VPNConnetionRoute -routemetric 1 add "1" to the current metric, which is not what i want. I want to replace it by 1.

Because i can't rely on an interface ID, since it may varies between 2 user, i tried to do it dynamically with the following command : 
`netsh interface ipv4 set interface "VPN Name" metric=`1
(because this one, `route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0  192.168.76.2 METRIC 3 IF 11` need an IF Number, which may varies).

It does work with netsh, but only if the "VPN Name" interface is connected, else it is not found.

---

Do you know :

- A way to find the interface without having to connect on it.
- a way to specify the interface ID we want at the creation of the VPN ? (so i can use the second netsh method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution that is working for me.

You have to take the problem on the opposite side:

- Since you can't touch the VPN metric while having it disconnected, you may touch the metric of your internet card.
- The metric of VPN = Default metric + metric routes, in automode.

  - If default route 0.0.0.0 is lower than real default metric (which depend of your internet speed). it will be default route metric+ vpn route metric.

The solution is then , to let auto metric for vpn (which will depend on your internet speed and metrics of the routes you configured. By default by creating the route, it is 1), and fix metric of your internet card at more than your real metric.

My real metric is 36, In auto-mode, the vpn routes have a metric of 37. If i set internet (which mean, ethernet or/and wifi, you have to think about all options) metric to 50, the vpn will be prefered.

It's not THE answer to my question, but it's a way to overpass the issue.